Can I have controller for custom html element (to get context buttons update and delete)?
not sure if I am asking correctly. But I understood that controller is probably what I need. I want to have the functionality of custom plugin number 4 called Dialog - http://suneditor.com/sample/html/customPlugins.html#dialog But I do not want to insert a link but custom element named for example customElement.
I can modify the code provided for the sample plugin to custom HTML element is inserted but then I will loose the context dialog to update, unlink, or remove the element.
I my case I want only the update and remove icons.

Is that possible in Suneditor?
You test with https://jsfiddle.net/radek/qjoevast/12/ the very first line defines what HTML element is going to be inserted.
for var customElement = 'a' I get the context buttons
for var customElement = 'customElement' the correct element is inserted but not context buttons

I always wonder why some needs to close a question and does not leave any comment. To explain or suggest how to improve. Or give the answer ...

I have specified the places where you can get the context of update,remove with //$$$$$$$$$$$$$ in js code below,and also the place where you can create the custom element look for it.


var plugin_customElement = {
  name: "customElement",

  display: "dialog",

  add: function (core) {
    core.addModule([SUNEDITOR_MODULES.dialog])

    const context = core.context
    context.customElement = {
      focusElement: null,
      elementText: null,
      _element: null,
    }

    let element_dialog = this.setDialog(core)
    context.customElement.modal = element_dialog
    context.customElement.focusElement = element_dialog.querySelector(
      "._se_customElement_text",
    )
    context.customElement.elementText = element_dialog.querySelector(
      "._se_customElement_text",
    )

    let element_controller = this.setController_ElementButton(core)
    context.customElement.elementController = element_controller
    context.customElement._element = null

    element_dialog
      .querySelector("form")
      .addEventListener("submit", this.submit.bind(core))
    element_controller.addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.onClick_elementController.bind(core),
    )

    context.dialog.modal.appendChild(element_dialog)
    context.element.relative.appendChild(element_controller)

    // Attach click event listener to the editor
    core.context.element.wysiwyg.addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.onEditorClick.bind(core),
    )

    element_dialog = null
    element_controller = null
  },

  setDialog: function (core) {
    const lang = core.lang
    const dialog = core.util.createElement("DIV")
    dialog.className = "se-dialog-content"
    dialog.style.display = "none"
    dialog.innerHTML = `
            <form class="editor_customElement">
                <div class="se-dialog-header">
                    <button type="button" data-command="close" class="se-btn se-dialog-close" aria-label="Close" title="${lang.dialogBox.close}">
                        ${core.icons.cancel}
                    </button>
                    <span class="se-modal-title">Custom Element</span>
                </div>
                <div class="se-dialog-body">
                    <div class="se-dialog-form">
                        <label>Content</label>
                        <input class="se-input-form _se_customElement_text" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="se-dialog-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="se-btn-primary" title="${lang.dialogBox.submitButton}">
                        <span>${lang.dialogBox.submitButton}</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>`
    return dialog
  },
  onEditorClick: function (event) {
    const clickedElement = event.target

    // Check if the clicked element is a target (e.g., custom element)
    if (clickedElement.tagName === "CUSTOM-ELEMENT") {
      this.plugins.customElement.call_controller.call(this, clickedElement)
    } else {
      // Hide controller if the click is outside the custom element
      this.controllersOff()
    }
  },

  setController_ElementButton: function (core) {
    const lang = core.lang
    const icons = core.icons
    const controller_btn = core.util.createElement("DIV")

    controller_btn.className = "se-controller se-controller-customElement"
    controller_btn.innerHTML = `
            <div class="se-arrow se-arrow-up"></div>
            <div class="element-content">
                <span><span></span>&nbsp;</span>
                <div class="se-btn-group">
                    <button type="button" data-command="update" tabindex="-1" class="se-tooltip">
                        ${icons.edit}
                        <span class="se-tooltip-inner"><span class="se-tooltip-text">${lang.controller.edit}</span></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" data-command="delete" tabindex="-1" class="se-tooltip">
                        ${icons.delete}
                        <span class="se-tooltip-inner"><span class="se-tooltip-text">${lang.controller.remove}</span></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>`
    return controller_btn
  },

  open: function () {
    this.plugins.dialog.open.call(
      this,
      "customElement",
      "customElement" === this.currentControllerName,
    )
  },

  submit: function (e) {
    this.showLoading()
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    const submitAction = function () {
      if (this.context.customElement.focusElement.value.trim().length === 0)
        return false

      const contextElement = this.context.customElement
      const content = contextElement.focusElement.value

      if (!this.context.dialog.updateModal) {
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Creation
        const customElement = this.util.createElement("custom-element")
        customElement.textContent = content

        const selectedFormats = this.getSelectedElements()
        if (selectedFormats.length > 1) {
          const oFormat = this.util.createElement(selectedFormats[0].nodeName)
          oFormat.appendChild(customElement)
          this.insertNode(oFormat)
        } else {
          this.insertNode(customElement)
        }

        this.setRange(
          customElement.childNodes[0],
          0,
          customElement.childNodes[0],
          customElement.textContent.length,
        )
      } else {
      //$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Updation
        contextElement._element.textContent = content
        this.setRange(
          contextElement._element.childNodes[0],
          0,
          contextElement._element.childNodes[0],
          contextElement._element.textContent.length,
        )
      }

      this.history.push(false)
      contextElement.focusElement.value = ""
    }.bind(this)

    try {
      submitAction()
    } finally {
      this.plugins.dialog.close.call(this)
      this.closeLoading()
      this.focus()
    }

    return false
  },

  active: function (element) {
    if (element && element.tagName === "CUSTOM-ELEMENT") {
      if (
        this.controllerArray.indexOf(
          this.context.customElement.elementController,
        ) < 0
      ) {
        this.plugins.customElement.call_controller.call(this, element)
      }
      return true
    }
    // Hide controller for non-matching elements
    if (
      this.controllerArray.indexOf(
        this.context.customElement.elementController,
      ) > -1
    ) {
      this.controllersOff()
    }
    return false
  },

  call_controller: function (selectedElement) {
    this.context.customElement._element = selectedElement
    const controller = this.context.customElement.elementController
    const span = controller.querySelector("span > span")

    span.textContent = selectedElement.textContent

    // Position the controller near the selected element
    const offset = this.util.getOffset(
      selectedElement,
      this.context.element.wysiwygFrame,
    )
    controller.style.top = `${offset.top + selectedElement.offsetHeight + 10}px`
    controller.style.left = `${offset.left - this.context.element.wysiwygFrame.scrollLeft}px`

    controller.style.display = "block"

    this.controllersOn(controller, selectedElement, "customElement")
  },

  onClick_elementController: function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()

    const command = e.target.getAttribute("data-command")
    if (!command) return

    e.preventDefault()

    if (/update/.test(command)) {
      const contextElement = this.context.customElement
      contextElement.focusElement.value = contextElement._element.textContent
      this.plugins.dialog.open.call(this, "customElement", true)
    } else {
    //$$$$$$$$$$$$$ Remove
      this.util.removeItem(this.context.customElement._element)
      this.context.customElement._element = null
      this.focus()
      this.history.push(false)
    }

    this.controllersOff()
  },

  init: function () {
    const contextElement = this.context.customElement
    contextElement.elementController.style.display = "none"
    contextElement._element = null
    contextElement.focusElement.value = ""
  },
}

// Use the custom plugin
SUNEDITOR.create(document.getElementById("ex_dialog"), {
  plugins: [plugin_customElement],
  buttonList: [
    [
      {
        name: "customElement",
        dataDisplay: "dialog",
        title: "Custom Element",
        buttonClass: "",
        innerHTML: '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M12 2a10 10 0 1 1-10 10 10 10 0 0 1 10-10z" /></svg>'//$$$$$$$$$ Edit if required ,
      },
    ],
  ],
})
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>SunEditor Custom Button Example</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor/dist/css/suneditor.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor/dist/suneditor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor/src/lang/en.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suneditor@latest/src/plugins/modules/dialog.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@joeattardi/emoji-button@3.0.3/dist/index.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .wrapper {
        z-index: 1000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="ex_dialog"></textarea>
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>



I have only modified js. The above code is compataible with most type of custom element(like image, a,link,some marquee,etc.), I have demonstrated with <a>.
The key working is the active: and onEditorClick:  methods in above js, which helps to detect and launch the appropriate handles.
